# How to launch scheduled spark jobs even if previous jobs are still executing on rundeck?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rundeck

Why rundeck not launching scheduled spark jobs even if the previous job is still executing?

Rundeck is skipping the jobs set to launch during the execution of the previous job, then after the completion of its execution launch new job based on the schedule.

But I want to launch a scheduled job even if the previous job is executing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your workflow strategy, here you have an explanation about that:

https://www.rundeck.com/blog/howto-controlling-how-and-where-rundeck-jobs-execute

You can design a workflow strategy based on "Parallel" to launch the jobs simultaneously on your node.

Example using the parallel strategy with a parent job.

```
Example jobs:
```

Job [one](https://pastebin.com/a0DBR0Vf), Job [two](https://pastebin.com/98UWGat8) and [Parent](https://pastebin.com/dSJeT9Gb) Job (using parallel strategy).

Comment: The "Parallel" strategy runs all steps of a job in parallel on each node. Parallel Strategy doesn't make jobs run simultaneously.

Comment: You're right!, but you can use a parallel strategy in a parent job calling the other jobs (child jobs) to run at the same time, I did a little example that works (and I added in the answer): job one: https://pastebin.com/a0DBR0Vf - job two: https://pastebin.com/98UWGat8 - job parent: https://pastebin.com/dSJeT9Gb (using parallel strategy). Cheers!